# ELISP interactive function with both prefix argument and user input as optional arguments

Tags: function, arguments, lisp, elisp, option-type

In ELISP, the documentation for [`interactive` codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes) mentions:

> P -- Prefix arg in raw form.  Does not do I/O.
>   ...
>   s -- Arbitrary text, read in the minibuffer and returned as a string ... Prompt.

I presumed that I could write a function with an optional prefix argument, as in:

```lisp
(defun some-function (&optional prefix)
    (interactive "P")
    ...
)
```

or a function with user input, as in:

```lisp
(defun some-function (user-argument)
  (interactive "sProvide an argument: ")
  ...
)
```

but not both. Then I found the Org-mode function `org-match-sparse-tree`, which I can call with `C-u C-c \`, where the prefix argument restricts the match to open org-mode headings and I am still prompted for a match. The source code is below and I cannot find how the variable `match` is assigned:

```lisp
(defun org-match-sparse-tree (&optional todo-only match)
  "..."
  (interactive "P")
  (org-agenda-prepare-buffers (list (current-buffer)))
  (let ((org--matcher-tags-todo-only todo-only))
    (org-scan-tags 'sparse-tree (cdr (org-make-tags-matcher match))
           org--matcher-tags-todo-only)))
```

How does this function take both prefix argument and user input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does this function [interactively] take both prefix argument and user input?

It doesn't -- the `match` argument is not obtained, and is therefore `nil`.  What you're seeing is the effect of the subsequent call to `(org-make-tags-matcher match)` with that `nil` value as the argument:

```el
(defun org-make-tags-matcher (match)
  "..."
  (unless match
    ;; Get a new match request, with completion against the global
    ;; tags table and the local tags in current buffer.
    (let ((org-last-tags-completion-table
           (org-tag-add-to-alist
            (org-get-buffer-tags)
            (org-global-tags-completion-table))))
      (setq match
            (completing-read
             "Match: "
             'org-tags-completion-function nil nil nil 'org-tags-history))))
  ...)
```

---

Functions *can* take multiple `interactive` arguments, though.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `interactive`

> To pass several arguments to the command, concatenate the individual strings, separating them by newline characters.

The very first example in that help demonstrates this:

```el
(defun foo (arg buf) "Doc string" (interactive "P\nbbuffer: ") .... )
```

This is elaborated upon at `(elisp)Using Interactive` -- up one level in the documentation you'd linked to:

```
It may be a string; its contents are a sequence of elements
separated by newlines, one for each argument(1).  Each element
consists of a code character (*note Interactive Codes::) optionally
followed by a prompt (which some code characters use and some
ignore).  Here is an example:

     (interactive "P\nbFrobnicate buffer: ")

The code letter ‘P’ sets the command’s first argument to the raw
command prefix (*note Prefix Command Arguments::).  ‘bFrobnicate
buffer: ’ prompts the user with ‘Frobnicate buffer: ’ to enter the
name of an existing buffer, which becomes the second and final
argument.
```

---

You should read that documentation fully, though -- there are more sophisticated things you can do, including writing arbitrary elisp to produce the interactive arguments (which may or may not involve prompting the user).

Comment: Well done. I had mistaken the part about multiple arguments separated by newlines, and that `No I/O` applies only to the prefix argument, not the other arguments.